# Toggle text between arrays ( jQuery )

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, replace

I have two arrays and the idea is to find text in first array and replace itwith the value of second array ( Same index ).

Example

Text to search & replace: **Visina**

```
var array1 = ['Visina','Tezina']; 
var array2 = ['Height','Weight'];
```

So the script should search for "Visina" in first array, find the index and replace with the value from second array with same index.

Also, it needs to toggle.

Comment: What result do you expect? Could you give an example.

Comment: Example:

I have a form with labels on English language, when user clicks button for "Serbian" it should search from array1 an index and replace with text from array2 with the same index. Also, when he click English again, it should toggle and return English version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you simply should use [Array.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method:

```js
var array1 = ['Visina', 'Tezina'];
var array2 = ['Height', 'Weight'];

function swap(str) {
  const index = array1.indexOf(str);
  if (index !== -1) {
    array1[index] = array2[index];
    array2[index] = str;
  }
}

swap('Visina');

console.log(array1);
console.log(array2);
```

Comment: Its working, but Visina should be with Height and Tezina with weight